# C# How to catch exception in a Task without block UI using wait

Tags: c#, asynchronous, try-catch, task

I have this code in a button click

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Msg.Clear();
        stopWatch.Reset();
        timer.Start();
        stopWatch.Start();
        lblTime.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("#");
        progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                     Reprocess();
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     Msg.Add(new clsMSG(ex.Message, "Error", DateTime.Now));
                     timer.Stop();
                     stopWatch.Stop();
                     throw;
                 }
             });
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

and this on the Reprocess method

```
private void Reprocess()
    {
        try
        {
            clsReprocess reprocess = new clsReprocess(tbBD.Text, dtpStart.Value, 50000);
            reprocess.Start(reprocess.BD);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

when the Reprocess method fails, the Task goes to catch, but the throw fails (the throw inside catch (Exception ex)) and the UI blocks until the reprocess.Start method is completed.
I have two questions:

- First: How can I catch the throw in the catch of my button?
- Second: How can I prevent the UI blocks?

I hope you can understand me, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why did you insert those `catch` handlers that do nothing? I always wondered why people are doing this hence I'm asking.

Comment: @usr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009773/using-catch-without-arguments

Comment: I'm catching the error (on the Task) for show in a DatagridView, the problem is that the system continues doing the Reprocess method, after that catch

Comment: System catch an exception (on reprocess.Start(reprocess.BD))

Comment: @Gabe what I mean is: Why catch and rethrow immediately? This never does anything.

Comment: @usr ahh sorry my mistake, long day. That's enough internet for me

Comment: Please cleanup your code, get rid of unnecessary `try .. catch { throw; }` blocks, use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`, move your `catch (Exception ex) {...}` block below the `await`, and don't EVER access any UI controls from a background thread.

Comment: It's counterproductive to give direct instructions without reasoning. Try explaining _why_ the OP should do it? Educate, not humiliate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Task.Factory.StartNew`; `Task.Run` is both safer and shorter to write.

Also, you can only access UI controls from the UI thread. This may be the cause of the problems you're seeing, if `Msg` is data-bound to the UI. Even if it's not, you don't want to access unprotected collections (e.g., `List<clsMSG>`) from multiple threads.

Applying both of these guidelines reduces the code to:

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Msg.Clear();
  stopWatch.Reset();
  timer.Start();
  stopWatch.Start();
  lblTime.Text = stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("#");
  progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
  try
  {
    await Task.Run(() => Reprocess());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Msg.Add(new clsMSG(ex.Message, "Error", DateTime.Now));
    timer.Stop();
    stopWatch.Stop();
    throw;
  }
}
```

If `Reprocess` throws an exception, that exception will be placed on the task returned from `Task.Run`. When your code `await`s that task, that exception is re-raised and caught in the `catch`. At the end of the `catch`, the code will re-raise that exception (`throw;`).

Comment: Should I disable Just My Code? because if it's enabled when `Reprocess` throws the exception the `catch` on the button doesn't catch it, I need to press F5 to continue.

Comment: @AbdelPosada: I think it's fine the way it is.